# Проблема с программой

Tags: python

Программа выдаёт ошибку: SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

```
m = input()
d = input()
while True:
    d += 7
    if m % 2 == 0 and d > 31:
        d -= 31
        m += 1
    elif m % 2 != 0 and d > 30:
        d -= 30
        m += 1
    if m > 12:
        break
    print(m, d)
```

Comment: нет, не выдает.

Answer (score 1):

вы вводите строку, чтоб ее перевести в число надо преобразовать **int()**
**m = int(input())

d = int(input())**

```
m = int(input())
d = int(input())
while True:
    d += 7
    if m % 2 == 0 and d > 31:
        d -= 31
        m += 1
    elif m % 2 != 0 and d > 30:
        d -= 30
        m += 1
    if m > 12:
        break
    print(m, d)
```